# Two UIImageViews with same frame but not overlapped exactly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

First UIImageView is created with frame (0,38,250,250) and second UIImageView is created with first view's frame and added as sub-view of first image view. The result shows the first image view is not exactly covered by second image view. Why both views are not overlapped? I assigned two imageview with different background colors so it is easier to see.

```
UIImageView *firstView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,38,250,250)] autorelease];
[firstView setBackgroundColor:RGBACOLOR(36, 39, 39, 0.8)];
[self.view addSubview:firstView];

UIImageView *itemPic = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:firstView.frame] autorelease];
itemPic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"color_c.png"];
[itemPic setBackgroundColor:RGBACOLOR(150, 150, 35, 0.8)];
[firstView addSubview:itemPic];
```

[image: two imageviews are not exactly overlapped]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frames are defined in different coordinate systems. Each view's frame is defined in its parent view's coordinate system. That coordinate system usually has (0.0, 0.0) as the top left corner of the parent view. A subview with a frame that does not have origin (0.0, 0.0) will not align with its parent view.

To always get a subview to align with and fill its parent view, use:

```
view.frame = parentView.bounds;
```

Answer (score 1):

The subview is being offset by the frame's offset you need to `initWithFrame:firstView.bounds`. Bound is a `CGRect` that has no offset(origin is 0,0).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add second view to first then create frame for second `CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250);` In this case both views will have identical coordinates.

If you want to add second subview to `self.view` then create it with `firstView.frame`. In this case both views will have identical coordinates.